# .htaccess ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I got this error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` on chrome when I add this code to my `.htaccess`:

```
# Redirect old Page URLs to new URLs
# Old URL format: http://example.com/?page=pagename
# New URL format: http://example.com/page/pagename
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page/%1? [R=301,L]

# Redirect old Search URLs to new URLs
# Old URL format: http://example.com/search.php?search=keyword
# New URL format: http://example.com/search/keyword
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} search.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search/%1? [R=301,L]

# Redirect old Post URLs to new URLs
# Old URL format: http://example.com/post.php?id_post=1
# New URL format: http://example.com/post/1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} post.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_post=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ post/%1? [R=301,L]

# Support new SEO-friendly URLs
RewriteRule page/(.*) ?page=$1
RewriteRule search/(.*) search.php?search=$1
RewriteRule post/(.*) post.php?id_post=$1
```

Could you guys tell me wheres the error please, already tried to figure it out but couldn't find what the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rules are internally rewriting the target url to itself. You need to use `%{THE_REQUEST}` to prevent this behavior as these variables do not match  internal redirects.

```
RewriteEngine on

#--Redirect from "/?page=foo" to "/page/foo"--#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?page=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [NC,L,R]
#--Rewrite "/page/foo/" to "/?page=foo"--#
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

#--Redirect from "/search.php?search=foo" to "/search/foo"--#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?search=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1? [NC,L,R]
#--Rewrite "/search/foo/" to "/search.php?search=foo"--#
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?search=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: oh it works :) but posts is missising could you add to your code aswell please thanks :P